# Balluff BIS M-410 Write To Tag

Tags: c#, rfid

I want to write numeric data to the RFID Tag with Balluff BIS M-410 series Tag Reader and Writer. I can read data from the Tag but i can't write to the RFID Tag. The steps is here. It from Balluff pdf.

[image]

And my function is here :

```
public void WriteTag()
{
    byte[] b = new byte[17];

    b[0] = 0x02; //command header
    b[1] = 0x011; //command size
    b[2] = 0x0006;  // command id

    b[3] = 0x0000;
    b[4] = 0x0000;   //Start Adres

    b[5] = 0x0000;
    b[6] = 0x0006;  //Lenght

    b[7] = 0x007D;
    b[8] = 0x007D; //timeout value

    b[9] = 0x0001;
    b[10] = 0x0002;
    b[11] = 0x0003;
    b[12] = 0x0004;
    b[13] = 0x0005;
    b[14] = 0x0006;

    b[15] = 255;
    b[16] = 255;

    serialPort1.Write(b, 0, 17);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command size is wrong. You say there will be 17 bytes of *data for the command*, while you send 17 bytes *altogether*. The device is probably waiting for more data. This can be seen in the example: it says the length is `0x0c` and if you count the bytes after the command ID there are 13 bytes there.

I assume using the device as big endian is ok (length is sent as such), but where is the command terminator `0x03`? Why is there `0xff 0xff` in the end?

Also as a style thing I wouldn't use `0x0006` as a literal when the variable is a byte. It doesn't do anything wrong but easily gives the impression of a 16bit variable.